WITH (NOLOCK) /SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED on stagnant data
I will prefix this by saying I may be misunderstanding / misinterpreting something here!
Our IT dept requests we update queries / stored procedures to use NO LOCK.  I need to add that to every stored procedure and every table etc.  Could I just put: SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED instead at the top of the stored procedures?
Further, it seems the reason they feel it necessary is if someone is querying a table without using NOLOCK, it locks the table/record causing other users querying the same tables to have their query (and mine) slow down. Is that true? Am I misunderstanding this? I thought NOLLOCK had to do with reading data that might be being updated and whether to wait for the update or simply take the value present at the time.  Am I wrong?
Some background. Our data warehouse is refreshed early morning during which data is typically appended. History could be updated as well but mostly new monthly data is added. Using NOLOCK here, if I did not want to wait for the 'updates' and was fine with whatever value was present could be worth it if it speeds things up, especially since I am generally interested in the seldom changed history only, not new month records being appended.
FYI I run queries/procedures during the dw refresh maybe 1% of the time. I would think the NOLOCK here could benefit ME.  But once the dw is refreshed for the day does NOLOCK or SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED help me in any way? Does using it help other users query data while I am?
Thanks!
I have tried each but cannot see a real difference in runs times thus far.

using NO LOCK is something you should actually almost never do, why would they tell you that

"Our IT dept requests we update queries / stored procedures to use NO LOCK." Your IT department have terrible ideas...

"Further, it seems the reason they feel it necessary is if someone is querying a table without using NOLOCK, it locks the table/record causing other users querying the same tables to have their query (and mine) slow down" This is utter nonsense... NOLOCK doesn't do what it says on the tin, it still results in locks. A SELECT query is not going to block another SELECT query. If you are getting contention between 2 or more SELECTs that's far more likely due to bad/lack of indexing or poor resource availability to the service/host.

Bad habits: putting nolock everywhere

not expected from IT dept to suggest that.
as per design, no lock can give wrong result which can even cause issues with your business logic. 2 selects acquire shared locks. So if your query is slow, its not becuase of lock but lack of resources. in case your query is slow due to writes ....
Why not use RCSI or snapshot isolation?

"Our IT dept requests we update queries / stored procedures to use NO LOCK." - your IT dept clearly has no idea. Using NOLOCK can actually return incorrect data.

Long and short of it: if you want outright performance, either use TABLOCK to block the whole table, or set the whole database to readonly (so no locking). If you just want to prevent blocking then use SNAPSHOT isolation. There is almost never a reason to use NOLOCK at all. And doing it in a DW refresh window is absolute madness: the index will be moving all over the place and you will very likely get wildly incorrect data.

I mostly agree with others: nolock is a bad idea. However, I'll temper it that we don't know your environment. I once worked at a billing office where the REAL data and accounting system was an old Vax minicomputer. We had a nightly Export/Load operation from the Vax to SQL Server. Users would access these tables, but changes went to other tables (so we couldn't change global isolation level). Using nolock on this semi-static data was absolutely fine, and might have marginally helped performance. But this was not a common scenario! Generally, you should not do this.


"it seems the reason they feel it necessary is if someone is querying a table without using NOLOCK, it locks the table/record causing other users querying the same tables to have their query (and mine) slow down. Is that true?" Only partly. Locks are usually done per row or per page, rather than per table. Anywhere skipping these locks helps you be faster, it's extremely likely you're also in a place where the two queries will step on each other's toes and someone gets wrong data.


Are you running reports over a very large/busy OLTP system? Are the reads often deadlock victims? I have worked on large/busy systems were setting TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED was used when the use cases were known and generally the only way to get a long running reports to complete. Long reads against a big/busy OLTP are not ideal. While using NOLOCK without knowing the implications and/or nature of the data queried can lead to other issues. Large and long running transactions can be ignored if you know that the data being introduced or updated is of no use to your query.

@RossBush That's factually incorrect. If a page split occurs at the same time, or an index rebuild, then the data is going to move around, and therefore may be read twice or not at all. See my linked duplicate, there are more situations than you might think that can cause incorrect data. The long running transactions should be using SNAPSHOT isolation instead.

@Charlieface - "The long running transactions should be using SNAPSHOT isolation instead" That is a pipedream for systems with 20+ years of tech debt most of which was created wrong in the first place.

and...I think they wanted NOLOCK in case their update query happened to be running when others were running SELECT queries...

I thought at first that was to protect the result of my SELECT query...but it was portrayed (or possible falsely interpreted by me) as  stopping SELECT queries from locking the tables so updates could be performed...

.OR so if no update query is running but several SELECT queries are running we don't lock each other out......the latter of which I think (after reading here) is rubbish...you will always have contention. This is really what I was checking.  I did not want to be locking up records about to be updated (though 99% of the time my SELECT queries would not be running at that time) nor did I want to LOCK a table so an other user 's SELECT query could not get data slowing them down....again my interpretation is NOLOCK does not help with that....you always have contention...


Our IT dept requests we update queries / stored procedures to use NO LOCK

Your "IT dept" is giving you bad advice because never ever, even you put NOLOCK or READ UNCOMMITED everywhere, no queries that writes data can run without locks. In this case NOLOCK / READ UNCOMMITTED isolation level is ignored...
Additionnaly in some cases NOLOCK is ignored too for SELECT queries (like those that decrypt encryted data)...
The best approach for your case will be to activate optimistic locking instead of the, by default, pessimistic. This can be done globally by modifying the database parameter with the command :
ALTER DATABASE CURRENT
   SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON;

Beware, for long and big transaction you will need to have a huge volume of storage for tempdb that caches versionned data for optimistic locking.

perhaps I misunderstood the IT dept...no sense arguing with them. Bottom line, if it is knowna table will NOT be updated and multiple users are querying the table...does NOLOCK have any impact in so far as how fast a query returns data.

@Robert_Fuschetto NOLOCK does not make the query faster, but avoids in certain circumstances and only for queries doing exclusively reading being blocked by other users, at the risk of having inconsistent data (unread line or read several times )...

Techie stuff aside, If a table being queried and WILL NOT be being updated by any other process but is SELECT queried by potentially several queries at the same time....does NOLOCK have any impact whatsoever?

@Robert_Fuschetto the system cannot "undestand" if there are row or not qualified under the WHERE clause to be updated or not until all rows have been read, except if the WHERE (or HAVING or OFFSET / FETCH...)  is a trivial one always false like 1 = 0...
